# Problems with XLConnect library - Windows 64 bit

Tags: r, xlconnect

I just started with Rstudio programming and I have some issues with XLConnect.

I was able to install "XLConnect" package, then tried to load the "XLConnect" library and got an error as below.

```
library(XLConnect)

ERROR: package or namespace load failed for'XLconnect':

.onload failed in loadNamespace() for XLConnect, details:

Call. System2("cat",c("/etc/*-release"), stdout =TRUE, stderr = TRUE) error: ' "cat" not found.



sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Italian_Switzerland.1252 LC_CTYPE=Italian_Switzerland.1252 LC_MONETARY=Italian_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Italian_Switzerland.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.0 tools_4.1.0 rJava_1.0-4
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, I hope for my sake you have found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in XLConnect 1.0.3, where it requires `cat` to be installed on Windows. We fixed it in 1.0.4, so upgrading is the easiest way to fix the problem.

If for some reason you can't upgrade, you may try to install `cat` on Windows, e.g. using [MINGW-w64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/).

See https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues/132 for the discussion.